# Dotnet publish not publishing DLL to publish directory

Tags: c#, .net-core, nuget

I want to publish my self contained .NET Core (2.2) application, however one specific NuGet package (`Microsoft.Management.Infrastructure`) is never published to the `publish` folder (as in the .dll file is not present).

I'm using the command `dotnet publish -c Release --self-contained -r win-x64 ConsoleApp1`. When running the application inside visual studio, everything works. However when running the compiled executable, I get a `FileNotFoundException`:

> Unhandled Exception: System.IO.FileNotFoundException: Could not load
>   file or assembly 'Microsoft.Management.Infrastructure,
>   Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35'.
>   The system cannot find the file specified.    at
>   ConsoleApp1.Program.Main(String[] args)

## To reproduce

1) Create a simple .NET Core console app (I tested both 2.1 and 2.2, no difference)
2) Add the NuGet package `Microsoft.Management.Infrastructure`
3) Add the following code to the application:

```cs
namespace ConsoleApp1
{
    internal class Program
    {
        private static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            var sessionOptions = new DComSessionOptions
            {
                Timeout = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(30)
            };

            CimSession Session = CimSession.Create("localhost", sessionOptions);

            var processors = Session.QueryInstances(@"root\cimv2", "WQL", "SELECT * FROM Win32_Processor");
            foreach (CimInstance processor in processors)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(processor.CimInstanceProperties["Name"].Value);
            }

            Console.ReadLine();
        }
    }
}
```

4) Publish the project: `dotnet publish -c Release --self-contained -r win-x64 ConsoleApp1`
5) Run the compiled executable

Comment: https://github.com/PowerShell/PowerShell/issues/7886

Answer (score 17, accepted):

The [MMI package](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.Management.Infrastructure) is composed of multiple assemblies which are specific to the Windows version i.e.: `win10-x64`, `win10-x86` `win8-x64` etc.

Thereby, you must use a version-specific target runtime (for example: `win10-x64`) instead of the generic `win-x64`. Using the publish command from below, the MMI DLL is included in the publishing procedure.

```
dotnet publish -c Release --self-contained -r win10-x64 ConsoleApp1
```

Comment: Still solves the issue! Thanks a lot

Comment: This has been bugging me for near 2 years and this is the solution, thank you so much!